# Data which relates to multiple Schemas in MongoDB?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, relational-database, non-relational-database

I have a front-end app which sometimes requests all the days of a month, sometimes the weeks of the year (more precisely: *the days* these weeks contain);

I thought of saving everything in mongodb like this:

```
{
 month: 'Feb',
 weeks: [ 
    [{ day: 'Mo', etc. }, { day: 'Tu', etc. } ], 
    [ week2 here etc.] ], //etc.   
 ] 
},
{
 month: 'Mar',
 weeks: [ 
    [{ day: 'Mo', etc. }, { day: 'Tu', etc. } ], 
    [ week2 here etc.] ], //etc.
  ]
}
```

... but this won't work for obvious reasons. Not every month has 4 weeks starting from Monday etc.

How would I realise something like this in MongoDB (roughly), so that my front-end app can request months (=an array of all the days of a month), but also weeks (= an array of 7 day-objects, starting from Monday)? I would really appreciate some hints here, as I am a novice.